# Spring Boot webapp doesn't load webjars and css

Tags: jsp, spring-boot, web-applications, webjars

I have a Maven webapp with Spring Boot and JSP. I'm trying to import webjars to use bootstrap on my JSP, I add the dependencies on my pom (locator included) and I put the resource handler on my webconfig:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.7-1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
  <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
  <version>0.30</version>
</dependency>
```

Now I add the references on my webconfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
 
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
          .addResourceLocations("/webjars/");
    }
}
```

And then I try to import the jars in my JSP:

```html
<script src="/webjars/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But it doesn't work. I put css inside webapp folder but I cannot link it inside my JSP.

How can I solve this? What's wrong?

PS: I have my JSP in `web-inf/jsp/pages` and I have added a context path to `application.properties` (but I think there are some conflicts with the `WebConfig` class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `@EnableWebMvc`, you have indicated to Spring Boot that you want to take complete control of configuring Spring MVC. That means that all of its auto-configuration of static resources, web jars support, etc has been switched off.

You can delete your `WebConfig` class entirely as it is duplicating configuration that Spring Boot will do for you automatically. If you need to customise the default configuration, you should implement `WebMvcConfigurer` as you have done, but omit the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation.

Comment: thanks it works!! To load css I have created the static folder inside resources. I put my css folder there and I import it by `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/package.css">`. PS: I have also removed the class as you said and add to the jars path the context I have added to the properties file

Answer (score 5):

add the `resourceChain` and set it to false like this :

```
 registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("/webjars/").resourceChain(false);
```

This is apparently not a webjar-locator problem.call to `resourceChain()` method should be necessary for configuration of webjar-locator.

Comment: This helped me, but unfortunately the link is broken and I cannot find the corresponding issue

Comment: @evandor, thank you for your comment, i removed the link.

Answer (score 2):

Add the below class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity//(debug=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().requestMatchers(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest)
        .antMatchers("/webjars/**");
    }

}
```

Comment: The question makes no mention of Spring Security so there's a good chance that this code will fail to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` to your JSP file. This fixed it for me.

```
 <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's easy. Try this

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
```